# error while creating Controller file in MVC3 under visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to learn MVC3 from the tutorial in **www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials**
Everything was working fine till i reach [**this step**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller)
Here after whenever i try to create a controller file under Controller folder i am getting error as displayed in following link:
[**click this to see the error message**](http://tinypic.com/r/zufj8h/8)

My Connection Sting is as follows:
`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=ShrathSample;uid=sa;pwd=admin123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`
I couldn't find the correct solution. Please somebody help to get out of this error or suggest me a simple tutorial to learn MVC easily.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace following connection string

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf"
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

with the following

```
<add name="MovieDBContext"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=Movies;User ID=sa;password="
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

for more information check out :-

[Add Controller in MVC4 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172074/add-controller-in-mvc4-not-working)

[Error when creating a Controller in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323307/error-when-creating-a-controller-in-visual-studio-2012?rq=1)

Comment: hi, @Neel, I am not using local mdf database in my application instead i am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: I have some links in my answer check it out @shary.sharath

Comment: and for your temporary solution comment your connection string then you will be able to add controller @shary.sharath