# Unable to retrieve metadata - MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller

I was following [**this**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) to create a simple **MVC** application. After creating the model, when I tried to add controller, I got the following error :

**Unable to retrieve metadata for "MvcApplication.Models.Movie". Invalid value for key "attachdbfilename".**

[image]

Can someone tell why I am getting this error.

**Update** : I saw [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445786/add-controller-error-unable-to-retrieve-metadata) wherein solution is provided by changing the providerName. But in my case it is already **System.Data.SqlClient**. Following are my connectionStrings :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication-20130708120940;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I am guessing you moved Movies.mdf, now when compiled it cannot be found.

Comment: ASP.NET tutorial doesn't say to add it.

Comment: Your movie DbContext connection string attaches Movies.mdf. `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf`

Comment: Yes. I am not sure where will be this directory.

Comment: `App_data` directory.

Comment: I am getting the same problem Nitish. Were you able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is saying invalid value for `AttachDbFilename` which is part of your `MovieDbContext` connection string.

The connection string currently shows this `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf` so it appears the mdf file is now missing from the `App_Data` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. the problem is the "|DataDirectory|". I Changed "|" to "\"

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem.  Even though I am new to MVC, I am bit embarrassed to say, I was trying a work around for another problem I was having and moved my SetInitializer into my classname : DbContext class.

The app worked just fine and the database was created fine as I changed the models but I couldn't add new controllers or modify current controllers using the scaffolding tool.

I began receiving errors.  One of them is listed above and another is:
                          Unable to retrieve meta data for 'namespace.Models.class'. A file 
                          activation error occurred. The physical file name '\name.mdf' 
                          may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the 
                          operation. 
                          CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. 
                          Check related errors.

Moving the SetInitializer back into my Global.asax fixed the problem.