# Newbie Error in ASP.NET MVC 4 : Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata, dbcontext

I'm a complete newbie in ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm following this nice [tutorial about ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller),

And I'm stuck at one point.

I'm trying to add a new Controller called `MoviesController.cs`, but Visual Studio 2010 is yielding the error :

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcMovie.Models.Movie'. Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
```

I think by `attachdbfilename`, it is referring to this line in Web.Config file :

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have also searched for this in StackOverFlow, one solution was to install Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0, I installed it but nothing changed.

### May be related:

I also have WAMPServer installed on my Windows 7 64-bit, but I have stopped all services and closed the application before I did anything.

So how do I solve this issue?

Thanks !

### Edit

Now I started to think that |DataDirectory| Should be changed with a path. is it true? if so, which path?

And what is this Movies.mdf file? Is is some kind of .sql file? And should I have already created it at some location?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525905/unable-to-retrieve-metadata-mvc-application/17526947#17526947

Comment: The MDF file is mentioned about half way down the tutorial at a bit titled `Working with SQL Server LocalDB`. Also there is a cracking set of tutorials from Scott Allen free here which I recommend watching: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/pluralsight-building-applications-with-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks ! So I need to change it to App_Data? And what if I want it to connect to my WAMPServer Database ? Or even another database like SQLite or remote ?

Comment: DataDirectory == App_Data. Different database types just mean a different connection string.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much man. I found the solution btw, I'm posting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this topic : http://forums.asp.net/post/5120530.aspx

It worked when I changed the line to this :

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

I also installed Sql Server Data Tools, but not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: what if i use sql server 2012 ??

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Express, then the connection string needs to be modified. I modified and used the below connection string and it worked for me.

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Movies;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: My problem was with MySQL, but your answer is helpful too. +1.