# Server error in ASP.NET application when I am trying to connect to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a problem with my first ASP.NET webforms app. I'm following a Microsoft tutorial. When I'm running the application to create the database for first time, this error appears in the browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

I'm not sure if my connection string is fine
`DESKTOP-6ANEE4G\MSSQLSERVER01` this is the name of my database.

Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(DESKTOP-6ANEE4G\MSSQLSERVER01)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WingtipToys" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(DESKTOP-6ANEE4G\MSSQLSERVER01)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: See what happens if you replace `(DESKTOP-6ANEE4G\MSSQLSERVER01)` with `(LocalDB)` or maybe `(LocalDB)\MSSQLSERVER01`

Comment: You can see what instances of local db you have on the command line with: `sqllocaldb.exe i`

Comment: Thank you, I changed it there but I still have the same error, it will have something to do with this??:
AttachDbFilename = | DataDirectory | \ wingtiptoys.mdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP .Net MVC 4, Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976725/asp-net-mvc-4-invalid-value-for-key-attachdbfilename)

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thank you!  I'm closer, I change the data source and now I have a new error:                                                                                            Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Lagash\source\repos\WingtipToys\WingtipToys\App_Data\wingtiptoys.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.