# Mvc 4 Code First with Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to using mysql with asp.net mvc 4. 
Added reference.

- Mysql.Data.dll
- Mysql.Data.Entity.dll
- Mysql.Web.dll

Added web.config file in connection string.

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="Server=localhost; port=3306; Database=dbprojectname; Uid=root; Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Added Model

```
  public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
 public class DbEntities : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
 }
```

and create controller but i have a error

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'WSDashboard.Models.User'. Using the 
>   same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of
>   database servers is not supported. Instead, create a separate
>   DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to Retrieve Metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546545/unable-to-retrieve-metadata)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283820/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-4-and-the-code-first-development-ctp

Comment: I Tried it. Error 'Unsupported Context Type'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, it's duplicated, but the answer is here by Yurko: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25640707/3902210

[image]