# MVC-5 Using Complex type functions for stored procedures; creating Views gives error:'Unable to retrieve metadata for MyProject.Models.Movies_Result

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first

I have written some Stored Procedures (SPs) as an assignment for DBMS subject. Now I must use those SPs at client side. So I choose MVC.

Here I am using "Add Import Function" by right clicking on SP name displayed in "Model Browser" to create New Function for the SP.

I am able to create views that uses functions for Simple SP (that Does not involve any JOINS). BUT when I try to create View that uses functions which includes JOINS (Complex type function), it throws following error:

**There was an error running the selected code generator:'Unable to retrieve metadata for myProject.Models.Movies_Result**

I tried different things like updating EF version and removing the relationships between entities but nothing is useful.

Please also advice if there are other ways to create client app by focusing less on code but more on DBMS (as it is what I'm learning).

Thank you.

Comment: its not a good advise but if you want to learn only the DBMS and not .NET then you should use simply the DBCommand to call your Stored Procedures instead of Entitiy Framework . that will make it simple instead of complexity in EF .

Comment: @Haroonnasir thank you for your help. I will definitely try DBCommand. Can you also help me with the issue mentioned above in the question, thanks again.

Comment: the above problem might be because the JOINS consists of different tables data in them and to create the view for them your model should also have the the properties from other table or may be you will have to make a ViewModel that contains all models of corresponding tables involved in JOINS  . OR it can be this issue . check this out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546545/unable-to-retrieve-metadata)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. The classes generated from Stored Procedure Functions have all the required fields including those foreign key fields. I think yes I need to create ViewModels. Will let you know how VM works for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Data Context Class (highlighted in picture) worked and it created the View.

[image: **enter image description here**]