# Unable to create new controller using entity framework scaffolding template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Code First with Entity Framework 4.

When I try to create new controller by selecting scaffolding option 
**"MVC controller read/write actions and views , using Entity Framework"** I get this error message:

> Unable to retrieve metadata for "Myproject.Models.example"  using the
>   same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of 
>   dataserver is not supported. Instead create a separate DbCompiledModel
>   for each type  of server being used.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Ddid u find something to make this work...?

Comment: Please show your model code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by commenting out the constructor in my `DbContext` class, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12165320/1397117).