# .net mvc add viewpage by scaffolding throw error There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'SByte' of primitive type 'SByte'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I add a viewpage, use by scaffolding, it's throwing an error that

> there is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'SByte' of 
>     primitive type 'SByte'.

below image:

### [image: entity info image]

[image: error image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 Scaffolding Add Controller gives error "Unable to retrieve metadata..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165185/mvc4-scaffolding-add-controller-gives-error-unable-to-retrieve-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your connection string target the correct database and that is capable of handling the datatype which is in the error specified.